# where can i get a backdrop like this?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Was looking for a backdrop (if that's what its called) for a scene i have in blender. If you look at this image you can see a glowing orb at the back of the image, providing light, i think its called a lightdrop but i am not sure. What is this called and where can  i get it?

[image]

I have tried adding a sphere with an emission shader and rendering it, then using the compositor to add a fog glow effect. didn't work. what are some other methods?

Comment: Add a white plane perpendicular to the camera and light it with a spot light

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple white plane, perpendicular to the camera and a spot light aimed at it should be enough.

[image]

The Lamp size will determine how soft the edge is and the spot shape size will determine the radius for the light. Make the light intense enough to have desaturation in the center.

Comment: no light is coming from the spot light

Comment: @Optimus please... In order to get help please be more specific. No one can guess what you are doing, don't wait for others to keep asking you questions. How did you set up the light? What intensity, what scale are you using? How can we help if we know nothing about your scene, your settings , etc... Edit your question and add images that show what you have tried.

Answer (score 6):

I would create a material on a plane with a spherical gradient.

[image]

The method to tweak this gradient is changing the colorramp or the RGB-curve.  As you can see, the Fac slider of the RGB-curve is on 2.5. I used it to overexpose the white.

Maybe it's better to adjust the color in the last step but that you have to test by your self ;-)

[image]